# HTML / PHP contact form doesn't send data to my gmail

Tags: php, html, email, contact-form

i've been trying to fix this one with solutions i've found here and in other foruns but nothing seems to work. I'm really noob with PHP. I don't know if this info is relevant but i'm hosting my project at byethost.com which they say it supports PHP.

I have made a contact form in my HTML contact page, made a PHP file to process the data and send it to my gmail adress. It says message successfully sent, but the data never arrives at my inbox on gmail. I've tried changing the PHP code (with copy paste solutions) in alternative ways but with no luck. I've also tried to sent it to my hotmail account but it doesn't work either. Can anyone help me?

Here is the HTML contact form:

```
     <div id="form_wrap">
        <form method="post" action="form_process.php" id="contact_form" class="contact">
                <label>
                    <span>NOME*</span>
                    <input name="nome" type="text" tabindex="1" required>
                </label>

                <label>
                    <span>E-MAIL*</span>
                    <input name="email" type="email" tabindex="2" required>
                </label>

                <label>
                    <span>TELEFONE*</span>
                    <input name="phone" type="tel" tabindex="3" required>
                </label>

                <label>
                    <span>WEBSITE</span>
                    <input name="website" placeholder="http://" type="url" tabindex="4">
                </label>

                <label>
                    <span>MOTIVO DE CONTACTO*</span>
                    <select class="escolha" name="motivo" size="1" tabindex="5" required>
                    <option>Contratá-lo</option>
                    <option>Fazer uma pergunta</option>
                    <option>Dizer olá ou agradecer</option>
                    </select>
                </label>

                <div>
                <label>
                    <span>MENSAGEM*</span>
                    <textarea name="message" tabindex="6" required></textarea>
                </label>
                </div>

                <div>
                <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Enviar" id="submit">
                </div>

        </form>
            <a class="subtop" href="#subtop">&#8211; Voltar ao topo</a> 
        </div>
```

Here is my form_process.php:

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$motivo = $_POST['motivo'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = "mygmailadress@gmail.com";
$subject = "Site contact form";

$header = "From: ".$fromText."\r\n";
$header .= "Cc: ".$ccText."\n";
$header .= "Reply-To : ".$fromText."\r\n";
$header .= "Return-Path : ".$fromText."\r\n";
$header .= "X-Mailer: PHP\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $header, $message, "From: " . $nome);
}
if(@mail($emailRecipient, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
  echo "Mail Sent Successfully";
}else{
  echo "Mail Not Sent";
}
?>
```

Comment: where is `$emailRecipient` defined ?

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to header injection.

Comment: as i said im a total noob with PHP i made this code out of tutorials and such, can you show me the corrected code? in jsfiddle if you want.

Comment: years later, did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Why twice mail function?

1. mail has 4 parameters, you give 5 params (from is a paert of fourth, it should be in $header)
2. variable `$emailRecipient` used in your mail function doesn't exists.
3. in 'from' header should be an e-mail address (and name), not only a non-mail string

Comment: as i said im a total noob with PHP i made this code out of tutorials and such, can you show me the corrected code? in jsfiddle if you want.

Comment: The correct code is `mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);`. If zou want to add 'from', add that into `$header`. And you can check the manual too: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: thank you for your reply, i tried the code in the answer below, which i think is your solution on the comment, but it doesn't work, i get the message successfully sent, but nothing goes to my inbox (or spam i checked it too), i'll check the manual. In the meantime do you know and actual PHP code that works? One that you arleady used with success?

Comment: Fromtext, cctext, etc. Many varibles you did not declare before u used them. Sorry, i write from phone only.  There could be a problem, mail funkcion and params are okay.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible reasons that the email never arrives.

It could be caught in spam, blocked by your host or your mail function could be incorrectly setup in your php.ini file.

However, from your code it looks like you are using the mail() function incorrectly.

You are trying to send the email twice by calling the function twice.  Just call it once like:

```
  if(mail(...)) {
    echo 'good times';
    } else {
    echo 'boo, no email was sent';
    }
```

Secondly you are using the function incorrectly.  According to the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) the mail function takes five arguments like so:

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

`$additional_headers` and `$additional_parameters` are optional as denoted by the [square brackets].  `$to`, `$subject` and `$message` are required in that order.

Thirdly  I heavily suggest NOT using the built in mail() function.

I suggest using [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).  It's a fully comprehensive PHP library which will look after you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i've already tried a more correct (answer below) code but it won't work on gmail or hotmail. I'm guessing it only works on domain emails. I will look into swiftmailer see if it can work for me.

Comment: To support this "It could be caught in spam, blocked by your host ..."
i had a similar situation. When i use a hotmail account, it works, but not with a gmail. Further info : https://support.google.com/a/answer/55299?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

U are trying to send mail twice you are using wrong variable names.

This code works for me.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $website = $_POST['website'];
    $motivo = $_POST['motivo'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $to = "asdf@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Site contact form";

    $header = "From: ".$email."\r\n";
    $header .= "Cc: ".$email."\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To : ".$email."\r\n";
    $header .= "Return-Path : ".$email."\r\n";
    $header .= "X-Mailer: PHP\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $header))
    {
      echo "Mail Sent Successfully";
    }else{
      echo "Mail Not Sent";
    }

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, i tried your code (changed the email address of course) but it does the same thing, says message successfuly sent, but nothing goes to my inbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you are usinf free hosting, they probably restrict your ability to send email.
Something like that is happening:

https://www.freehosting.com/client/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=25

PHP mailing functionality is limited on free account to prevent abuse. To make it working, your mailing script should be configured to use SMTP server 'cpanel.freehosting.com' and to authenticate against it using credentials of email account set up in cpanel.
Paid accounts are provided with unrestricted access to PHP mailing functionality.

You can find more info on setting up email authentication in PHP scripts at this link:
http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm

Optionally, PHP mail() can be enabled by purchasing corresponding addon HERE.